# Can't seem to import bootstrap into wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to import a page I made in bootstrap into Wordpress and I can't seem to figure it out.

I would like someone to give me some hands-on support if they have the time. I get different results with different attempts.

I changed my index.html to home.php and suddenly the entire site goes down. Restored it again and did something else and then the site showed up without its CSS. i understood i had to create a functions.php file where i call the stylesheets but im not getting any further.

What do i need to do to succesfully import a bootstrap page as theme in wordpress?

Comment: This site isn't a forum; it's more of a direct Q&A site. Please check the "how to ask" a question. I'd love to help but you've not provided enough detail as to what you are attempting, the results you are getting and what is amidst.  Please restructure your question to be more appropriate for SO. I will add that Bootstrap itself is not a wordpress theme. There might be "bootstrap *based* themes for wordpress" but that is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a WP theme, or just a WP page template (in case of just one page.)

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

In your current theme, if you have page.php , duplicate it by saying e.g. page-custom.php

In the template header section name the template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

Below it add your bootstrap page's code, you may need to fix paths to css/js files but I am sure you will figure that out by googling.

Once you have that page as WP template. Now create a page in WordPress to which you want to apply that bootstrap template.. and in the page edit sidebar, there is section you can select that custom template you created.
see this photo:
https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/basics-page-templates-03.png

Now if you will visit the page on the front-end , that page will have bootstrap design applied from your custom template.